# Auth Issue using httpx

Tags: python, python-requests, httpx

Valid Response:

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as req:
    req.auth = authdata
    req.headers.update({
        'x-amz-access-token': access
    })

    r = req.get(
        'https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/orders/v0/orders/', params=params)
    print(r)
```

But using `httpx` am getting:

```
import httpx
async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client:
    client.auth = authdata
    client.headers.update({
        'x-amz-access-token': access
    })
    r = await client.get('https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/orders/v0/orders/', params=params)
    print(r)
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\AmericaN\Desktop\Lab\code.py", line 60, in <module>
    trio.run(main)
  File "C:\Users\AmericaN\Desktop\Lab\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\trio\_core\_run.py", line 1932, in run
    raise runner.main_task_outcome.error
  File "c:\Users\AmericaN\Desktop\Lab\code.py", line 56, in main
    await get_orders(authdata, await get_token())
  File "c:\Users\AmericaN\Desktop\Lab\code.py", line 49, in get_orders
    r = await client.get('https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/orders/v0/orders/', params=params)
  File "C:\Users\AmericaN\Desktop\Lab\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1539, in get
    return await self.request(
  File "C:\Users\AmericaN\Desktop\Lab\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1361, in request
    response = await self.send(
  File "C:\Users\AmericaN\Desktop\Lab\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1396, in send
    response = await self._send_handling_auth(
  File "C:\Users\AmericaN\Desktop\Lab\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1428, in _send_handling_auth       
    request = await auth_flow.__anext__()
  File "C:\Users\AmericaN\Desktop\Lab\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\httpx\_auth.py", line 92, in async_auth_flow
    request = next(flow)
  File "C:\Users\AmericaN\Desktop\Lab\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\httpx\_auth.py", line 115, in auth_flow
    yield self._func(request)
  File "C:\Users\AmericaN\Desktop\Lab\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\requests_auth_aws_sigv4\__init__.py", line 109, in __call__
    p = urlparse(r.url)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 389, in urlparse
    url, scheme, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(url, scheme)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 125, in _coerce_args
    return _decode_args(args) + (_encode_result,)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 109, in _decode_args
    return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 109, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
AttributeError: 'URL' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved By using the following : [httpx-auth](https://github.com/Colin-b/httpx_auth#aws-signature-v4)